# ¿Cómo plantear el cálculo de series al infinito programáticamente?

Tags: c++

En esta serie no entiendo cómo plantear la parte "hasta n igual infinito". Infinito no existe, y si existiese entonces el programa en teoría nunca terminaría de ejecutarse. ¿Cómo se implementan este tipo de operaciones?

Aquí dejo una imagen donde se muestran lo que me piden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int main () {

 int i=0, n=1;

 while (i<n) {

     i++;
     n++;

     cout <<i<<endl;

 }

 getch();
 return 0;

}
```

Por el momento tengo esto que me muestra todos los números desde el 1 hasta el infinito(porque el programa no termina de ejecutarse), pero al momento que quiero llevar esta lógica a mi problema no me compila y me trabo.

Comment: Hola! Por favor te incito a que te pases por el [Tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/Tour) para que aprendas como funciona nuestra comunidad, dado que este tipo de preguntas se interpretan como _"Hazme la tarea"_, te recomiendo que pongas un poco de lo que has intentado y los problemas que tienes. Saludos! :)

Comment: @NaCl acabo de editarlo para que no luzca un problema de "Hazme la tarea". Creo que ahora es más convincente y propio a recibir una respuesta.

Comment: en matemáticas, esta sumatoria TENDERÍA a un valor, pero al ser a infinito, nunca va a llegar al valor exacto....  lo que yo haría sería una función que después de cada ciclo compare el valor nuevo de N con su valor anterior, y parar si no ha cambiado significativamente, por ejemplo, menos de 0.00001 o algo así.  O se puede topar a un número de ciclos....

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor solución será iterar hasta encontrar que más iteraciones ya no aportan más precisión significativa al resultado.

En las series convergentes, como es el caso, el hecho de añadir más términos al sumatorio no modifica el valor final como tal sino que aporta más precisión al resultado, por lo que infinito sería el número de elementos necesarios para obtener la máxima precisión. Si asumimos que nuestro nivel de precisión no es necesario que sea infinito podemos disminuir el número de elementos del sumatorio.

Un ejemplo del código sería algo de este estilo (creo que funciona pero no lo he probado, tal vez no compile por alguna tontería,revisatelo):

```
double limite (void)
{
    int n = 1;
    double dif = 1.0f;
    double value = 0.0f;

    for (n = 1 ; dif > 0.001f ;  ++n) //Valor de ejemplo, pon la precisión que tu quieras
    {
       dif = 1.0f/n*(n+1);
       value += dif;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Depende de lo que te hayan pedido exactamente igual tienes que modificar un poco el código pero la idea sería esta.

Answer (score -1):

El planteo del problema es criticable.

Si a lo que se refiere es a calcular una *aproximación numérica* de la serie, entonces, sí, uno debería decidir con qué aproximación va a trabajar, qué tipo de datos usará para almacenar las sumas parciales, y armar un bucle que evalúe las sumas parciales hasta que el valor no cambie (dentro de la tolerancia admitida), como en la respuesta de Pako LordPakus.

Pero esto tiene varios potenciales peligros: uno debería tener algún criterio para, o bien garantizar de entrada que la serie converge, o bien poner una cantidad máxima de iteraciones (si no, corremos el peligro de no terminar nunca).
Además, el criterio de que el enésimo término aporte un delta pequeño puede no ser suficiente para decidir que hay que truncar ahí. Eso solo puede garantizarse por un análisis previo (matemático, no computacional) de la serie particular.

Otra cosa muy diferente es intentar una solución simbólica de la serie por medios computacionales; esto sería verdaderamente "hallar la serie", pero esto es muchísimo más difícil de hacer en general, sólo programas como [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) son capaces (hasta cierto punto) de hacer algo por el estilo.

Comment: Es verdad que un delta pequeño no es condición suficiente, (caso extremo, que a partir de cierto n todos los elementos fueran pequeños pero de valor constante), pero en este caso es una serie convergente y de tipo cuadrático inverso, es decir, generalmente de convergencia rápida. Evidentemente si el caso pedido hubiese sido otro, la solución propuesta habría sido otra, pero buena apreciación.